# error: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I have coded Binary Tree traversals and its height in C++ but when compiling after a bit of coding but I keep getting the error: Return Statement with no value, in function returning 'int' (-fpermissive).

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *left;

    node(int val)
    {
        data = val;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

void Preorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    cout << root->data << " ";
    Preorder(root->left);
    Preorder(root->right);
}

void Postorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    cout << root->data << " ";
    Postorder(root->left);
    Postorder(root->right);
}

void Inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    cout << root->data << " ";
    Inorder(root->left);
    Inorder(root->right);
}

int Height(node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    int left_height = Height(root->left);
    int right_height = Height(root->right);
    if (left_height > right_height)
    {
        return left_height + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return right_height + 1;
    }
}

/*
             1
           /   \
          2     3
        /  \   /  \
       4    5 6    7
*/

int main()
{
    struct node *root = new node(1);
    root->left = new node(2);
    root->right = new node(3);
    root->left->left = new node(4);
    root->left->right = new node(5);
    root->right->left = new node(6);
    root->right->right = new node(7);
    cout << "Preorder Traversal: ";
    Preorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Preorder Traversal: ";
    Postorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Inorder Traversal: ";
    Inorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The height of the tree is: ";
    cout << Height(root) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image]

I am getting this error in calculating the height of the tree.
I have used int data type in the function height i.e `int Height(node *root)` and also I am returning value `right_height + 1` or `left_height + 1` but still I am getting this error.

Comment: `return;` does not return an `int`.

Comment: @Eljay but I am returning the value. The main problem is in Height function.I am returning value right_height + 1 or left_height + 1 but still I am getting this error.

Comment: The `Height` function is declared to return an `int` value. So then it must return an `int` value. And there is a path of execution where you `return` without a value.

Comment: `Height` must return an `int`, but `return;` returns nothing. You must fix the `root == NULL` case.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't use the old C compatibility macro `NULL`, use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 5):

You are not returning a value when root == NULL. If the node doesn't exist, the tree has no height, and so should return 0.

```
int Height(node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int left_height = Height(root->left);
    int right_height = Height(root->right);
    if (left_height > right_height)
    {
        return left_height + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return right_height + 1;
    }
}
```